# facing issue in converting gradle to kotlin dsl

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How to convert this to kotlin dsl?

```
buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        staging {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            consumerProguardFiles 'project-proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            consumerProguardFiles 'project-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Mainly facing issue in converting the staging part?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It would look like:

```
buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
    }

    getByName("staging") {
        isDebuggable = true // TODO it is assumption, you have to double check
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        consumerProguardFiles("project-proguard-rules.pro")
    }

    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        consumerProguardFiles("project-proguard-rules.pro")
    }
}
```

Source docs:
[Official android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/migrate-to-kts)
[Official gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/nightly/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html#script_file_naming)

Please also note there is an option to convert many things automatically over console command. This option requires more research.